# How to override single remote branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have 2 remote branches, `branch1` & `branch2`.

I created `branch3` locally by cloning `branch2`, and I want my `branch3` to be pushed with the overridden version of `branch2` as a new separate, independent branch.

The problem is that when I push my local `branch3` to the remote, `branch3` still contains the files from the `branch2`, which I deleted in the new `branch3`..

Is there any better way to fix this branch issue?

Answer (score 1):

You must stop the **tracking** to the *remote branch* from the local branch `branch3`, then the *remote branch* is `branch2`, because `branch3` was cloned from there:

```
$ git branch3 --unset-upstream
```

After this, push the local branch (`branch3`) new to remote, as a new independent *remote branch*:

```
$ git push -u origin branch3
```